# What is P4LOG? Why it's filled up?

Tags: perforce

In my company we're using a perforce and last time we started to receive "The filesystem 'P4LOG' has only XXX free, but the server configuration requires at least YYY available". What does it means. I tried to google and all I found is that this is env variable - `Name and path of the file to which Perforce errors are written.` We asked our administrator to fix the problem and he increased min file size, that removes an error for some time but later it appears again. Why this warning appears? How to prevent it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your administrator can either set up [Perforce's specific log rotation tool](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r12.2/manuals/cmdref/logrotate.html), or use the standard [Linux logrotate tool](http://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate).  This is essential if you don't want to keep running out of disk space on the Perforce server.

As the p4 logrotate docs mention, p4 logrotate happens automatically on a [checkpointing or journaling](http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB/2408/) event.  You should have checkpointing and journaling set up so that you don't run the risk of losing your entire depot if the p4 server has a problem.

Comment: And, once you've made a checkpoint and rotated your logs, you can copy the old logs and journals to a backup device (e.g., an external hard disk, or a network storage device, then remove them from the server's primary device to free up the space.

Answer (score 1):

Your administrator needs to let up log rotation.  Log rotation will compress recent logs and remove old ones.

Comment: Documentation says that `logrotate` is for the Structured Server Logs. Is `P4LOG` this kind of file? What info is written where? Also docs says it should rotate automatically.

Comment: There may be an ownership or permissions issue, or a cronjob may not be running.  What OS are you using?

Comment: I think linux. Btw documentation says `logrotate` does not rotate the unstructured P4LOG or P4AUDIT logs.

Comment: **logrotate** will rotate anything - it just has to be configured